# Best way to fill array in sequence and add all the elements of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Today someone asked me that how will you create an array with N sequential elements like `[1,2,3,...,N]` (should start from 1), where `N` is provided by the user. For example, if N=10 then the array will be `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`. In addition, he wanted to sum the elements, so if N=10 then the result is 55.

I have done this as follows:

```js
console.log(new Array(10).fill(1).map((x,y)=>x+y).reduce((x,y)=>x+y))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
.as-console-row{background: #000;color: #fff;}
.as-console-row-code{font-size:24px!important}
```

I just want to ask what is the best way to do the same problem and Why?

Comment: There are many options. It depends on what your criteria is for "best".

Comment: Best means time complexity and faster way

Comment: I don't think any semi-reasonable implementation would have time complexity greater than `O(N)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are still looking for the "[best](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128231/best-way-to-fill-array-in-sequence-and-add-all-the-elements-of-the-array#comment96998045_55128231)" solution considering execution time, the following one is 55 times faster than the solution posted by [Nina](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128254/1636522) (https://jsfiddle.net/vc1wmk6e/):

```js
function range (first, last) {
  var range = new Array(last - first + 1); range[0] = first;
  for (var i = 1; range[i - 1] < last; i++) range[i] = first + i;
  return range;
}

console.log(...range(1, 10));
console.log(range(1, 10).reduce((acc, x) => acc + x));
```

To know why it's (around 4.5 times) faster than `fill` + `map`, we need to look at the implementation of these two functions in order to calculate their time complexity. I'm not ready to dive into the JS source code right now, but there are chances that `fill` and `map` both iterate over the array elements. In this case the time complexity would be at least O(2N), while the `range` function is O(N). The remaining additional time may come from function calls that require lookups in memory to find the corresponding code, but this is a pure supposition :-|

Comment: this can directly give me range why loop will be fast ? `[...Array(size).keys()].map(i => i + startAt);`

Comment: @SourabhSomani Another test including your code (test3): https://jsfiddle.net/qgte6r1u/ (test1 > test3 > test2). Thanks for your vote, this is justice :-)

Comment: @SourabhSomani To be able to answer "why loop will be fast?", we need to analyze the time complexity of the spread operator (`...`), the `keys` function and the `map` function. However I'm not ready to dive into the JS source code right now, that's why I provided test cases :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could create an array with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) by using an object with length as property and map the incremented indices.

```js
var length = 10,
    array = Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => i + 1),
    sum = array.map((s => v => s += v)(0));

console.log(...array);
console.log(...sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

The formula for the sum of the first n natural numbers is n * (n + 1) / 2, which is much faster than messing around with arrays.

```js
function getSum(n) {
  return n * (n + 1) / 2;
}

console.log(getSum(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove your map as you're just doing sum up, you can do it in reduce itself

```js
console.log(new Array(10).fill(1).reduce((x,y,i) => x+y+i , 0))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
.as-console-row{background: #000;color: #fff;}
.as-console-row-code{font-size:24px!important}
```